# Im trying to validate a password and the error "cant convert from string to double" comes up

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

[This is a runtime error in visual basic and it should be pretty easy to fix but I dont know how.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVgZr.png)

Comment: forcing to use particular characters at positions severely limits the number of valid passwords, you should test if there is a Capital and a special character somewhere in the string

Comment: As per [ask] please post your code and error messages as text, not pictures

Answer (score 2):

[Mid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function) returns a `String` and [Asc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/asc-function) returns an `Integer`. Comparing the two results in syntax error. In order to fix it, you will need to explicitly convert your result from `Mid` into an `Integer`, for example via `CInt` if the result of `Mid` is numeric.